# Best way to retrieve the maximal length of a string from a Joi Schema?

Tags: javascript, joi

From this schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  type: Joi.string().required().allow('bug', 'feedback'),
  description: Joi.string().required().min(1).max(5000),
  console_logs: Joi.array().required().items(Joi.string()).max(5000),
  console_errors: Joi.array().required().items(Joi.string()).max(5000),
  file: Joi.string().allow(null).max(10000000)
}).options({ stripUnknown: true })
```

I want to retrieve the maximal length for the field "description", I found that the following code works:

```
schema.extract('description').$_getRule('max').args.limit
```

However, I am wondering if this is the "right" way to do this.

My use case is that the schema is shared between the front and the back, so when modifying it, it updates both the text field character limit and the backend validation.

Comment: Might be easier to add a `const DESCRIPTION_MAX_LENGTH` constant to the shared code that is used both in the schema and the text field.

Comment: @Bergi It was my initial thought, but for whatever reason I chose the hard road. Guess I will do that instead.